# Como recorrer un array con el index modificado

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, typescript, objeto

tengo un array de la forma

```
array[
P12, {color:blanco, ciudad: coruña ...}
P13, {color:negro, ciudad: coruña ...}
P25, {color:rosa, ciudad: beis ...}
P89, {color:azul, ciudad: coruña ...}
]
```

construí el array de esa forma para poder hacer una consulta de los mismos y poder imprimirlos en otras secciones de la web, ver sus valores o darles seguimiento, eso funciona bien,

```
console.log(array['P'+12].color)
```

lo que no me resulta es que necesito hacer un listado de todos ellos

he intentado recorrerla com map o find pero no me ha salido,
alumna idea por favor.

Comment: ¿Qué significan esos P12,P13...? no es Javascript válido

Comment: Te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida para conocer cómo se espera que se formulen las preguntas, qué es un [mcve] y ganarte una medalla extra :)

Comment: Los P12, P13 son índex que asigne para poder ubicarlos mas fácilmente.

Comment: Como dice @PabloLozano ese arreglo no es válido. Así como lo pones `P12, P13, P25 y p89` deberían hacer referencia a una variable, la cual no estas poniendo. Si es una cadena entonces se encierra en comillas, pero si es parte de un objeto clave-valor, esta mal creado. No sé como te funciona en tu sistema

Comment: si yo tampoco lo se, hice los cambio que digeron y funciono. ahora solo me queda intentar lo de la biblioteca que mecionaron por ahi,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si necesitas recorrer un array de objetos y qué cada uno tenga un índice para qué te sea más facil buscar puedes usar otra propiedad `index` por ejemplo para los mismos:

```
let array = [
    {color:"blanco", ciudad: "coruña" ,index:12},
    {color:"negro", ciudad: "coruña" ,index:13},
    {color:"rosa", ciudad: "beis" ,index:25},
    {color:"azul", ciudad: "coruña" ,index:89}

];
```

Luego si quieres recorrer el array para buscar algún objeto que satisfaga un índice qué quieras lo puedes hacer con `forEach`:

```
let num= 1; //Aquí puede usar el qué quieras o cargarlo de otra entrada. 

array.forEach(object=>{
    if(object.index === num){
        console.log(object.color);
    };
});
```

Comment: Excelente, encaminaste mi destino estimado amigo, podre obtener todo el array con ese index?

Comment: Exacto, el `forEach` recorre todo el array y en cada iteración toma como valor cada objeto del array, por lo tanto si, puedes obtener cualquier elemento dentro del mismo con un índice que quieras.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. Si, es que copié y pegué y no lo modifiqué, ya lo cambio.